# Change package name without changing file path

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, package-name

Is it possible to change the package name without changing the file path?

We have a project and we are considering submitting it to the store with a different package name. We want to be able to merge into the new project when we make changes to the previous project. I think git system will not detect changes in files if I change the file path.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Java packages should be the same as the file paths - whilst this is not required by the compiler, it will cause many tools to be unhappy; IDEs for example. Git will detect changes just fine - as long as the renames are picked up as renames not delete and add.

Comment: You are right. Even if the file path is different, it detects the changes in the pull request. However, it shows as conflict and I don't know how to solve it yet.